# Adding multiple Google Calendars with different keys to FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Whilst I fully understand the instructions given in the docs (shown below for completeness...), it is not clear how to add any other Google calendar that would require a different Google key.

The standard form that separates out the key:

```
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      googleCalendarApiKey: '<YOUR API KEY>',
      eventSources: [
        {
          googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com'
        },
        {
          googleCalendarId: 'efgh5678@group.calendar.google.com',
          className: 'nice-event'
        }
      ]
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
```

They mention using the extended form to add sources, which is simply adding more members to the array, but where does the additional Google Key go?

Has anyone got an example, please?

Comment: can i get a link to the documentation you are following?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo It'll be https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

Comment: YOur not using the google calendar api can you remove that tag to avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Right at the bottom of the documentation (at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar) it says

> If you need different API keys per calendar, you can set a
> googleCalendarApiKey option on each individual Event Source when
> written in extended form

The Event Source documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object) then expands on what "extended form" means:

> It must be a traditional JavaScript object with properties

followed by some examples.

So what you're doing already *is* the extended form of the event source.

I'm not able to test this right now, but I therefore expect that what you can do is add the API key to each object in the list of event sources:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  eventSources: [
    {
      googleCalendarApiKey: '<YOUR API KEY>',
      googleCalendarId: 'abcd1234@group.calendar.google.com'
    },
    {
      googleCalendarApiKey: '<YOUR OTHER API KEY>',
      googleCalendarId: 'efgh5678@group.calendar.google.com',
      className: 'nice-event'
    }
  ]
});
```